# Why is "the" not required in the phrase "Select call type"?

Tags: articles

Why is "the" not required in the phrase "Select call type"?

Why not "Select the call type"?

Context - app interfaces:

[image]

Comment: This is not English, it's telegraph-style wording in IT applications to save valuable space. Also, *The system has failed to connect the call, because we have no access to the microphone*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you take a look at posts from the past dealing with _headlinese_, and _telegraphese_, you will see that this type of question comes up quite frequently, hence the VTC as duplicate.

Comment: @Yosef It's the telegraphese style of English rather than standard English.